# Implementing Z-Clipping algorithm to basic 3D engine in Microsoft Makecode Arcade

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, makecode

I have made a basic 3D engine in microsoft makecode arcade, it currently renders a 3d cube that you can walk around and rotate, but the z-clipping is horrible and makes it an unpleasant experience. I want to implement something like they show in [this scratch tutorial](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/747504673/), but I'm not really good at that kind of stuff.
If you want to help, [go to this link to edit the code](https://arcade.makecode.com/#pub:S31625-93058-36938-23345)

Thanks!

At first I tried to just not render a triangle if any one of its vertices were behind -140z, but that wasn't very visually appealing as triangles disappear once they got close